# Error: Compile Error: sObject type 'KnowledgeArticleVersion' is not supported.

Tags: class, error-handling, apex-code

I am getting an error on what looks like an object that no longer exists. When trying to deploy unrelated Apex Triggers into production, it will not let me due to this error. Has anyone seen this? And do you have any recommendations?

### Code

```
public with sharing class KnowledgeArticleViewerController {
    public KnowledgeArticleVersion article {get; set;}
    private Id articleId;

    public KnowledgeArticleViewerController(ApexPages.standardController stdController) {
        articleId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

        List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articles = [SELECT Id,Title FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online'];

        ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Got article ids: ' + articles.get(0).Id 
         + ' ' + articles.get(1).Id + ' ' + articles.get(2).Id) );

        article = articles.get(0);

    }
}
```

### End Code

> Error: Compile Error: sObject type 'KnowledgeArticleVersion' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 8 column 44

There is no `KnowledgeArticleVersion` object and this code was implemented 2+ years before I got here.

Answer (score 0):

*I had a similar problem (exact same error), but it was for a Bot running an Apex class. I'll share the solution in case others come here for the same permission problem.*

---

You need to make sure your Bot (or app) has permissions for the `KnowledgeArticleVersion` object.

**Setup** ➡ **Permission Sets** ➡ `sfdc.chatbot.service.permset` (change this if it's for your app) ➡ **Object Settings**

Then:

- Choose `Knowledge`

  *The `KnowledgeArticleVersion` object is under `Knowledge` (The 1st option for me. The 2nd `Knowledge` option had 0 **Total Fields**)*
- Give `Read`,`View All` permissions
- Save
- Go back and try again.